# How to mock a method that creates a new instance of an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a method that instantiates an object and I want to mock the behavior of the newly created instance. How do I go about doing this in xunit tests?

Here is the method I am trying to unit test. I would like to mock the behavior of client (`RestClient`)

```
public async Task<TaUser> GetUser(string username)
{
    string token = await _cognitoPoolService.GetToken();

    RestClient client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(resource: _getbEndpoint, method: Method.POST);

    var requestBody = new GetTaUserRequest() { Username = username };
    request.AddJsonBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody));

    request.AddHeaders(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}")
    });

    IRestResponse response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);

    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IdentityProviderUser>(response.Content);

    if (user.Outcome.StatusCode == 200)
        return user.User;
    else
        throw new Exception($"{user.Outcome.Message} ");
}
```

Comment: Which mocking library are you using? The free libraries (e.g Moq) usually can't mock newly created instances, only the commercial ones (e.g JustMock). Instead of creating the restclient in your method you should inject it to your class and then it is easy to mock with any mocking library.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance of `RestClient` as an argument to your method. You can use an overload with the default behaviour.

```
public async Task<TaUser> GetUser(string username)
{
   return await GetUser(username, new RestClient(_baseUrl));
}

public async Task<TaUser> GetUser(string username, RestClient client)
{
   // your code
}
```

Now it is no problem to use a different implementation of RestClient.

Comment: This worked but now i am faced with the need to mock IRestClient